# Problems installing Ruby on OS X

Tags: ruby, osx-mavericks

Upon navigating to a directory using Ruby on Rails, i'm told that

`ruby-1.9.3-p374 is not installed.`

`To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p374'`

I type the instructed commands, and the installation halts at the following message:

`Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
please read /Users/MyName/.rvm/log/1383070768_ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.`

I'm confused as to how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read /Users/MyName/.rvm/log/1383070768_ruby-1.9.3-p374/make.log ? What did it say?

Comment: You'll need to hold your monitor closer to the camera. We can't read what's on it.

Comment: Which are the versions of your `Mac Os X` and the `gcc`?